# Калькулятор услуг jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу написать калькулятор услуг, нашел на просторах интернета скрипт, теперь пытаюсь подогнать под себя. Возникли трудности с выводом конечной суммы. Вот, что у меня получилось [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oe7befen/1/), а хочу, чтобы работало как на сайте http://it-in.ru/calculator/, точно так же.

На данные об услугах внимания не обращайте, ибо я их не трогал пока что. Хочу сделать, чтобы вне зависимости от блоков и тд. можно было выделить любой набор услуг и их сумма появилась в "Итого".

Вот сам скрипт

```
    function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
  number = (number + '')
    .replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '');
  var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number,
    prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
    sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
    dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
    s = '',
    toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
      var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
      return '' + (Math.round(n * k) / k)
          .toFixed(prec);
    };
  // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
  s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n))
    .split('.');
  if (s[0].length > 3) {
    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
  }
  if ((s[1] || '')
      .length < prec) {
    s[1] = s[1] || '';
    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1)
      .join('0');
  }
  return s.join(dec);
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    //Заменяем кнопку <button>рассчитать стоимость</button> на <span class="cur"></span>, в который будет подставляться рассчитанная сумма
    $('.price-button').click(function() {
        var boxPrice = $(this).closest('.col-md-4');

        function hideButton () {
            $(boxPrice).find('.price-button').hide();
            $(boxPrice).find('.footer-price').append('<h4>Итог: <span class="cur"></span> <span class="rub">р. / м.кв.</span></h4>');

        };
        //анимация раскрытия блока с параметрами
        $(boxPrice).find('.box-price').animate({height: '390px'}, {'duration': 500}, {'easing': 'linear'}, hideButton());

    });

    //отслеживаем выделение параметра, чтобы в блоке был только 1 выделенный элемент

    $('ul.parametrs li').click(function() {
    //  var listParam = $(this).closest('ul.parametrs');
    //  $(listParam).find('li.check-param').removeClass('check-param');
        var elemParam = $(this);
        $(elemParam).toggleClass('check-param');

    /*  $('ul.parametrs li.check-param').click(function() {
            $(elemParam).removeClass('check-param');
        });*/

        var elemAttr = $(elemParam).attr('data-param');
    });


    ////////////Калькулятор
    //получаем значения параметров
    function valParam () {
    /*  var Price = $('.box-filter').attr('data-price'); //получаем стоимость кв.м.*/
        //var roofValue = $('#roof').val();//вычисляем высоту потолков
        var total = 0;
        var paramValuePol = 0;
        var paramValueSteny = 0;
        var paramValuePotolok = 0;
        paramValuePol = $('#pol').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param');

        paramValueSteny = $('#steny').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param');
        paramValuePotolok = $('#potolok').find('li.check-param').attr('data-param');


        total += +paramValuePol + +paramValueSteny + +paramValuePotolok;//формула расчета общей стоимости
        /*  var newtotal = Math.round(total);//округляем*/
        total = parseInt(total);

            $('.cur').html(total);
            $('.rub').show();
        };


    //отслеживаем изменение данных
    $('.calculator').on('click', valParam);

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работающий пример https://jsfiddle.net/v2pwww/b98e059L/3/

Исправленная ф-я

```
function valParam ($this) {

    $this.toggleClass('check-param');

    var isChecked = $this.hasClass('check-param');
    var total = parseInt($('.cur').html());
    var param = $this.data('param');    
    var group = $this.closest('div.way');
    var groupList = $(group).find('.check-param');

    if (groupList.length > 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < groupList.length; i++) {

            var $el = $(groupList[i]);
            var elCheked = $(groupList[i]).hasClass('check-param');

            if (elCheked) {
                $el.removeClass('check-param');
                total = total - $el.data('param'); 
            }          
       }

       total = total + $this.data('param'); 
       $this.addClass('check-param');

    }   

    if (isChecked) {
        total = total + param;
    } else {
        total = total - param;
    }

    $('.cur').html(total);
    $('.rub').show();

};
```

Это не нужно.

```
$('ul.parametrs li').click(function() {
    ....
});
```

По хорошему я бы не использовал в качестве определения групп родительский элемент `.way` Гораздо удобнее, более гибче и читабельнее — это добавлять к элементу с классом `.item` класс `.way` или еще лучше data атрибут, к примеру `data-group="way"` А родительский элемент `.way` пусть играет роль позиционирования на странице.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, мб подскажете напоследок, что переделать надо, чтобы добавлять класс `.way` к элементу?

Comment: Потренируйтесь сами, у вас достаточно вариантов уже;)

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто сделать такой подсчет https://jsfiddle.net/v2pwww/oe7befen/2/

Мои правки только в этих частях кода

```
function hideButton () {
    $(boxPrice).find('.price-button').hide();
    $(boxPrice).find('.footer-price').append('<h4>Итог: <span class="cur">0</span> <span class="rub">р. / м.кв.</span></h4>');
};

function valParam ($this) {

    var isChecked = $this.hasClass('check-param');
    var total = parseInt($('.cur').html());
    var param = $this.data('param');

    if (isChecked) {
        total = total + param;      
    } else {
        total = total - param;
    }

    $('.cur').html(total);
    $('.rub').show();
};


$('.label').on('click', function() {
    valParam($(this))
});
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы можно было выбрать только 1 услугу, из тех, что обернуты в `div class="way"`, https://jsfiddle.net/Lnmafg3o/, я сделал этот выбор, но он не верен, ибо по повторному клику по выделенному эл-ту с него не снимается выделение, а сумма постоянно растет. См. услуги "Адаптивная верстка" и "Неадаптивная верстка"

Comment: Это логичное поведение. Вы в двух местах слушаете событие `onclick` на элементах `.item`. Попробуйте сделать проверку на родительский элемент `.way` в ф-и `valParam`

Comment: `var listParam = $(this).closest('div.way');
$(listParam).find('.check-param').removeClass('check-param');` добавил в ф-цию valParam, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Во первых у вас тут ошибка. В данном случае `$(this)` из ф-и вернет объект `window`. Поскольку вы уже передает указатель на объект событием `onclick` -> `valParam($this)` нужно использовать переменную `$this`. Во вторых код надо дополнить — то что вы написали так как надо работать не будет. См. ответ ниже.